# Bad experience with lollipop 5.0 version

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, motorola-moto-g

I am facing lot of problems with lollipop version with my MOTO-G 1st Gen, after i upgraded to lollipop my mobile got very slow and frequently getting strucked at that time am able to see only white screen. and it is not allowing me even to switch off my mobile..

very bad experience with Lollipop 5.0 OS...

Answer (score 0):

I would try a factory reset

There are many that have this issue after a major upgrade and generally a reset and starting over will clear out anything causing issues